# Java PrintWriter not writing to file in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, printwriter

I am working on a jaxafx project where the user inputs the file and then writes to that file through another method.

So I have declared `File` and `PrintWriter` as static global variables. I also tried passing them but that didn't work either, I know global is bad OO. The file opens and closes fine and write inside the method I open it but none of the other methods will write to it.

I have tried a lot of flushes as you can see but I am stuck. Any ideas? I can include my libraries if needed;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import uNumberLibrary.EnhancedUNumber;
import uNumberLibrary.InexactUNumber;


class Convert {
    public boolean negative = false;
    public EnhancedUNumber TheValue;

    public boolean operandDefined = true;
    public Label label_errOperand = new Label("");

    public Convert() {

    }

    public Convert(String temp) {
        if (temp.length() > 0 && temp.charAt(0) == '-')
            TheValue = EnhancedUNumber.nextEnhancedUNumber(temp.substring(1), false);
        else
            TheValue = EnhancedUNumber.nextEnhancedUNumber(temp, true);
        TheValue = new EnhancedUNumber(TheValue, 50);
    }
}

public class Task3Solution extends Application {
    // Constants used to parameterize the graphical user interface. We do not use a
    // layout for
    // this application. Rather we manually control the location of each graphical
    // element.
    Convert One = new Convert();
    Convert Two = new Convert();
    Convert OneErr = new Convert();
    Convert TwoErr = new Convert();
    Convert Size = new Convert();

    private final double WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;
    private final double WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
    private final double BUTTON_SPACE = WINDOW_WIDTH / 6; // There are six gaps
    private final double BUTTON_WIDTH = 60;;
    private final double BUTTON_OFFSET = BUTTON_WIDTH / 2;

    // These are the major application values not associated with the user interface
    private EnhancedUNumber operand1;
    private EnhancedUNumber operand2;
    private EnhancedUNumber Erroperand1;
    private EnhancedUNumber Erroperand2;
    private Integer sizeD = 20;
    boolean operandError = false;
    boolean printing = false;
    private double new_window_hieght = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
    private int count=0;
    // These are the application values required by the user interface
    Label[] label = new Label[4];
    Label[] labPM = new Label[3];
    String texts[] = { "Inexact Printing Calculator", "First operand", "Second operand", "Result" };
    String plusMinus[] = { "±", "±", "±" };
    TextField text_Operand1 = new TextField();
    TextField text_Operand2 = new TextField();
    TextField Err_Operand1 = new TextField();
    TextField Err_Operand2 = new TextField();
    TextField text_Result = new TextField();
    TextField Err_Result = new TextField();
    TextField decimals = new TextField();
    Label printLabel = new Label("");// new Label("Enter the file name here:");
    Label printLabelErr = new Label("");// new Label("Replace existing file?");
    Label printLabelNew = new Label("");// new Label("New file");

    TextField PrintField = new TextField();
    Label dec = new Label("Size (>7) ");
    Label label_errOperand1 = new Label("");
    Label label_errOperand2 = new Label("");
    Button[] button = new Button[5];
    String But_texts[] = { "+", "-", "x", "÷", "\u221A" };
    Button printButton = new Button();
    String Print_text[] = { "Enable Printing", "Disable Printing" };
    Button printFileButton = new Button();
    String Print_File_text[] = { "Set file for printing", "Replace file for printing", "Close the file!" };
    static File file;
    static PrintWriter printWriter;

    /**********
     * This method initializes all of the elements of the graphical user interface.
     * These assignments determine the location, size, font, color, and change and
     * event handlers for each GUI object.
     */
    private void initializeTheGUIElements(Pane theRoot, Stage theStage) {
        // Label theScene with the name of the calculator, centered at the top of the
        // pane
        int ypos[] = { 10, 40, 130, 220 };
        int size[] = { 24, 18, 18, 18 };
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
            label[i] = new Label(texts[i]);
            Label l = label[i];
            l.setFont(Font.font("Arial", size[i]));
            l.setMinWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 10);
            l.setLayoutX(0);
            l.setLayoutY(ypos[i]);
        }

        int ypm[] = { 70, 160, 250 };

        for (int i = 0; i < plusMinus.length; i++) {
            labPM[i] = new Label(plusMinus[i]);
            Label l = labPM[i];
            l.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 24));
            l.setMinWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 150);
            l.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);

            l.setLayoutX(0);
            l.setLayoutY(ypm[i]);
        }

        // Establish the first text input operand field and when anything changes in
        // operand 1,
        // process both fields to ensure that we are ready to perform as soon as
        // possible.
        TextField t = text_Operand1;
        t.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        t.setMinWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 200);
        t.setMaxWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 200);
        t.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        t.setLayoutX(10);
        t.setLayoutY(70);
        t.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            One = new Convert(text_Operand1.getText());
            operand1 = One.TheValue;

        });
        t.setOnAction((event) -> {
            Err_Operand1.requestFocus();
        });

        t = Err_Operand1;
        t.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        t.setMinWidth(120);
        t.setMaxWidth(120);
        t.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        t.setLayoutX(WINDOW_WIDTH - 130);
        t.setLayoutY(70);
        t.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            OneErr = new Convert(Err_Operand1.getText());
            Erroperand1 = OneErr.TheValue;

        });
        t.setOnAction((event) -> {
            text_Operand2.requestFocus();
        });

        // Establish the second text input operand field and when anything changes in
        // operand 2,
        // process both fields to ensure that we are ready to perform as soon as
        // possible.
        t = text_Operand2;
        t.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        t.setMinWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 200);
        t.setMaxWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 200);
        t.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        t.setLayoutX(10);
        t.setLayoutY(160);
        t.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            Two = new Convert(text_Operand2.getText());
            operand2 = Two.TheValue;
        });
        t.setOnAction((event) -> {
            Err_Operand2.requestFocus();
        });

        t = Err_Operand2;
        t.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        t.setMinWidth(120);
        t.setMaxWidth(120);
        t.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        t.setLayoutX(WINDOW_WIDTH - 130);
        t.setLayoutY(160);
        t.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            TwoErr = new Convert(Err_Operand2.getText());
            Erroperand2 = TwoErr.TheValue;

        });
        t.setOnAction((event) -> {
            text_Result.requestFocus();
        });

        // Establish an error message for the first operand just above it with, right
        // aligned
        Label l = label_errOperand1;
        l.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        l.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        l.setMinWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 10);
        l.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        l.setLayoutX(400);
        l.setLayoutY(45);

        // Establish an error message for the second operand just above it with, right
        // aligned
        l = label_errOperand2;
        l.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        l.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        l.setMinWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 10);
        l.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        l.setLayoutX(400);
        l.setLayoutY(135);

        // Establish the result output field. It is not editable, so the text can be
        // selected
        // and copied, but it cannot be altered by the user.
        t = text_Result;
        t.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        t.setMinWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 200);
        t.setMaxWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 200);
        t.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        t.setEditable(false);
        t.setLayoutX(10);
        t.setLayoutY(250);

        t = Err_Result;
        t.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        t.setMinWidth(120);
        t.setMaxWidth(120);
        t.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        t.setEditable(false);
        t.setLayoutX(WINDOW_WIDTH - 130);
        t.setLayoutY(250);



        printButton = new Button(Print_text[0]);
        Button b = printButton;
        b.setFont(Font.font("Symbol", 10));
        b.setMinWidth(100);
        b.setMaxWidth(100);
        b.setMaxHeight(30);
        b.setMinHeight(30);
        b.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        b.setLayoutX(250);
        b.setLayoutY(370);
        b.setOnAction((event) -> {
            if (printing) {
                printButton.setText(Print_text[0]);
                printing = false;// enables printing and sets button to disable enlarge window
                theRoot.getChildren().remove(PrintField);
                theRoot.getChildren().remove(printFileButton);
                printLabel.setText("");
                theStage.setHeight(new_window_hieght + 40); // change the hieght

            } else {
                printing = true;
                printButton.setText(Print_text[1]);
                theRoot.getChildren().add(PrintField);
                theRoot.getChildren().add(printFileButton);
                printLabel.setText("Enter the file name here:");
                theStage.setHeight(new_window_hieght + 120); // change the hieght

            }
        });

        t = PrintField;
        t.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        t.setMinWidth(320);
        t.setMaxWidth(320);
        t.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        t.setEditable(true);
        t.setLayoutX(10);
        t.setLayoutY(440);
        t.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            file = new File(PrintField.getText());
            // PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter();
            if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
                printFileButton.setText(Print_File_text[1]);
                printLabelNew.setText("");
                printLabelErr.setText("Replace existing file?");

            } else {
                printLabelNew.setText("New file");
                printFileButton.setText(Print_File_text[0]);
                printFileButton.setDisable(false);
                printLabelErr.setText("");
            }
            //
            //
            // } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // printLabelErr.setText("Replace existing file?");
            // //printLabelNew.setText("New file");
            // //e.printStackTrace();
            // }

        });

        l = printLabel;
        l.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        l.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        l.setMinWidth(WINDOW_WIDTH - 200);
        l.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        l.setLayoutX(10);
        l.setLayoutY(410);

        l = printLabelErr;
        l.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        l.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        l.setMinWidth(200);
        l.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        l.setLayoutX(350);
        l.setLayoutY(410);

        l = printLabelNew;
        l.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 18));
        l.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        l.setMinWidth(200);
        l.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        l.setLayoutX(350);
        l.setLayoutY(410);

        printFileButton = new Button(Print_File_text[0]);
        b = printFileButton;
        b.setFont(Font.font("Symbol", 12));
        b.setMinWidth(200);
        b.setMaxWidth(200);
        b.setMaxHeight(30);
        b.setMinHeight(30);
        b.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        b.setLayoutX(350);
        b.setLayoutY(440);
        b.setDisable(true);
        b.setOnAction((event) -> {
            count++;

            //PrintWriter printWriter = null;
            printFileButton.setText(Print_File_text[2]);
            printLabelNew.setText("");
            printLabelErr.setText("Printing to file");

            try {
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
                PrintField.setDisable(true);

                if (printFileButton.getText().equals(Print_File_text[2]) && count%2==0) {
                    printFileButton.setText(Print_File_text[0]);
                    printFileButton.setDisable(true);
                    PrintField.setDisable(false);
                    printLabelErr.setText("");
                    printWriter.close();

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }
            //printWriter.println("printing right");

        });


        // this combines the four buttons into one loop
        for (int i = 0; i < But_texts.length; i++) {
            button[i] = new Button(But_texts[i]);
             b = button[i];
            b.setFont(Font.font("Symbol", 32));
            b.setMinWidth(BUTTON_WIDTH);
            b.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
            b.setLayoutX((i + 1) * BUTTON_SPACE - BUTTON_OFFSET);
            b.setLayoutY(300);
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                b.setOnAction((event) -> {
                    addOperands(printWriter);
                    printWriter.flush();

                });
                break;
            case 1:
                b.setOnAction((event) -> {
                    subOperands(printWriter);
                    printWriter.flush();
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                b.setOnAction((event) -> {
                    mpyOperands(printWriter);
                });
                break;
            case 3:
                b.setOnAction((event) -> {
                    divOperands(printWriter);
                });
                break;
            case 4:
                b.setOnAction((event) -> {
                    sqrtOperands(printWriter);
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**********
     * This is the start method that is call once the application has been loaded
     * into memory and is ready to get to work.
     * 
     * In designing this application I have elected to IGNORE all opportunities for
     * automatic layout support and instead have elected to manually position each
     * GUI element and its properties.
     * 
     */
    public void start(Stage theStage) throws Exception {

        theStage.setTitle("Amanda Martin"); // Label the stage (a window)
        Pane theRoot = new Pane(); // Create a pane within the window

        initializeTheGUIElements(theRoot, theStage); // Define all the GUI elements

        theRoot.getChildren().addAll(label[0], label[1], label[2], label[3], text_Operand1, label_errOperand2,
                label_errOperand1, text_Operand2, text_Result, button[0], button[1], button[2], button[3], button[4],
                labPM[0], labPM[1], labPM[2], Err_Result, Err_Operand1, Err_Operand2, printButton, printLabelErr,
                printLabelNew, printLabel);

        Scene theScene = new Scene(theRoot, WINDOW_WIDTH, new_window_hieght + 10); // Create the scene with
        // the required width and height

        theStage.setScene(theScene); // Set the scene on the stage
        theStage.setResizable(true);
        theStage.show(); // Show the stage to the user

    }

    private boolean binaryOperandIssues() {
        if (!One.operandDefined) { // Check operand 1 and set a
            label_errOperand1.setText("Missing a valid value"); // missing value error
            label_errOperand2.setText("");
        }
        if (!Two.operandDefined) { // Check operand 2 and set a
            label_errOperand2.setText("Missing a valid value"); // missing value error
            label_errOperand1.setText("");
        }
        if (operandError) // See if invalid input errors
            return true; // return true if so
        if (!One.operandDefined || !Two.operandDefined) // See if any missing input values
            return true; // return true is so
        label_errOperand1.setText("");
        label_errOperand2.setText("");
        return false; // Else okay input, return false
    }

    /*******************************************************************************************************
     * This portion of the class defines the computation that takes place when the
     * various calculator buttons (add, subtract, multiply, and divide) are pressed.
     */

    /**********
     * This is the add routine
     * 
     */
    private void addOperands(PrintWriter printWriter) {
        InexactUNumber Number1 = new InexactUNumber(operand1, Erroperand1);
        InexactUNumber Number2 = new InexactUNumber(operand2, Erroperand2);
        printWriter.println("Set Operand1 = "+Number1);
        printWriter.flush();

        printWriter.println("Set Operand2 = "+Number2);
        printWriter.flush();

        printWriter.println("Add ");
        printWriter.flush();


        if (binaryOperandIssues()) // If there is an operand error
            return; // just return. Otherwise, reset
        label_errOperand2.setText(""); // the "divide by zero error"
        InexactUNumber result = new InexactUNumber(Number1);// create a new uNUmberMod to not overwrite operand 1
        result.add(Number2); // perform the addition
        text_Result.setText(Number1.toStringBestEstimate()); // Converts the result to string
        label[3].setText("Sum"); // Specify the result is a sum
        Number1.roundTo(Math.abs(Erroperand1.getDP()));
        Err_Result.setText(Number1.toStringErrorTerm());
        printWriter.println("Result= "+Number1);
        printWriter.println();

    }

    /**********
     * This is the subtract routine
     * 
     */
    private void subOperands(PrintWriter printWriter) {
        InexactUNumber Number2 = new InexactUNumber(operand2, Erroperand2);
        InexactUNumber Number1 = new InexactUNumber(operand1, Erroperand1);
        printWriter.println("Set Operand 1 = "+Number1);
        printWriter.println("Set Operand 2 = "+Number2);
        printWriter.println("Subtract ");

        if (binaryOperandIssues()) // If there is an operand error
            return; // just return. Otherwise, reset
        InexactUNumber result = new InexactUNumber(Number1);// create a new uNUmberMod to not overwrite operand 1
        result.sub(Number2); // perform the subtraction
        text_Result.setText(Number1.toStringBestEstimate()); // Converts the result to string
        label[3].setText("Difference"); // Specify the result is a difference
        Number1.roundTo(Math.abs(Erroperand1.getDP()));
        Err_Result.setText(Number1.toStringErrorTerm());
        printWriter.println("Result= "+Number1);
        printWriter.println();
    }

    /**********
     * This is the multiply routine
     * 
     */
    private void mpyOperands(PrintWriter printWriter) {
        InexactUNumber Number2 = new InexactUNumber(operand2, Erroperand2);
        InexactUNumber Number1 = new InexactUNumber(operand1, Erroperand1);
        printWriter.println("Set Operand1 = "+Number1);
        printWriter.println("Set Operand2 = "+Number2);
        printWriter.println("Multiply ");

        if (binaryOperandIssues()) // If there is an operand error
            return; // just return. Otherwise, reset
        InexactUNumber result = new InexactUNumber(Number1);// create a new uNUmberMod to not overwrite operand 1
        result.mpy(Number2); // perform the product
        text_Result.setText(Number1.toStringBestEstimate()); // Converts the result to string
        label[3].setText("Product"); // Specify the result is a product
        Number1.roundTo(Math.abs(Erroperand1.getDP()));
        Err_Result.setText(Number1.toStringErrorTerm());
        printWriter.println("Result= "+Number1);
        printWriter.println();
    }

    /**********
     * This is the divide routine. If the divisor is zero, the divisor is declared
     * to be invalid.
     * 
     */
    private void divOperands(PrintWriter printWriter) {
        InexactUNumber Number2 = new InexactUNumber(operand2, Erroperand2);
        InexactUNumber Number1 = new InexactUNumber(operand1, Erroperand1);
        printWriter.println("Set Operand1 = "+Number1);
        printWriter.println("Set Operand2 = "+Number2);
        printWriter.println("Divide ");

        if (binaryOperandIssues()) // If there is an operand error
            return; // just return. Otherwise, reset
        InexactUNumber result = new InexactUNumber(Number1);// create a new uNUmberMod to not overwrite operand 1
        result.div(Number2); // perform the division
        text_Result.setText(Number1.toStringBestEstimate()); // Converts the result to string
        label[3].setText("Quotient"); // Specify the result is a sum
        Number1.roundTo(Math.abs(Erroperand1.getDP()));
        Err_Result.setText(Number1.toStringErrorTerm());
        printWriter.println("Result= "+Number1);
        printWriter.println();
    }

    private void sqrtOperands(PrintWriter printWriter) {
        if (operand1.isNegative()) { // Check to see if the value is
            label_errOperand1.setText("Square root of a negative value"); // negative. if so,
            text_Result.setText(""); // display the error message
        } else {
            label_errOperand2.setText(""); // Reset the "divide by zero error"
            // uNumberMod result = new uNumberMod(operand1,sizeD);

            EnhancedUNumber result = new EnhancedUNumber(operand1);

            EnhancedUNumber ErrResult = new EnhancedUNumber(Erroperand1);
            printWriter.println("Set Operand1 = "+result+" ± "+ErrResult);
            printWriter.println("Square Root ");

            ErrResult = new EnhancedUNumber(ErrResult); // System.out.println(result);

            result = new EnhancedUNumber(result); // System.out.println(result);
            ErrResult.div(result);
            result.squareRoot(); // Do the square root
            ErrResult.mpy(result);

            String theAnswer = result.toString(sizeD);// set theAnswer to the result with 8 characters
            text_Result.setText(theAnswer); // Converts the result to string
            label[3].setText("Square Root"); // Specify the result is a quotient
            text_Operand2.setText("");

            Erroperand1.div(new EnhancedUNumber("2", 1, true, Erroperand1.getDP()));
            Erroperand1.mpy(result);
            String theAnswerErr = Erroperand1.toString(sizeD);// set theAnswer to the result with 8 characters

            Err_Result.setText(theAnswerErr);
            printWriter.println("Result = "+result+" ± "+theAnswerErr);


        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); // for all JavaFX applications.
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try writing a much smaller, simple program that just prints to a file with PrintWriter.  You'll probably figure out the problem on your own by then.  Nobody is going to read all that code.

Comment: You've got just a single call to `PrintWriter.close` and it is only ever executed if you just opened the same `PrintWriter` before without writing anything. No wonder this fails...

Comment: Also consider using (existing) layouts extending `Pane` that place the nodes on their own. You're currently placing every single node individually. Just think about how much work it'll cost you to insert a single node at the top of the root pane. Also if you're doing a `for` loop and add a`switch` with a case for every single iteration of the loop to the body you're doing something wrong. You could move the logic from the switch below the loop and do`buttons[0].setOnAction(...);buttons[1].setOnAction(...);`or even create a helper method for creating and intiailizing the button and use no loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your printwriter object as an append mode.

```
printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true))), true);
```